# Wrong(?) return type of overloaded method Task.Run

Tags: c#, generics, task-parallel-library

I found in the book about programming asynchronous applications the following code:

```
public static double ReadDataFromIO() {
    // We are simulating an I/O by putting the current thread to sleep.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return 10d;
}

public static Task<double> ReadDataFromIOAsync() {
    return Task.Run(new Func<double>(ReadDataFromIO));
}
```

This code compiles without errors and works great. However I wanted to check which overloaded method of Task.Run ([MSDN - Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run%60%601%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)) is used here and didn't find any.

Moreover Visual Studio indicates that:

```
Task.Run<double>(Func<double> function)
```

is used.

How is it possible?

Comment: Which bit do you find non-obvious? The generics? The `Func`? or...?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: The non-obvious part for me is that in code the non-generic version of Task.Run is called, but in reality Task.Run<double>(Func<double> function) is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the silent `<double>` - that is generic parameter inference, and it happens routinely in C#. Basically, *if* you don't specify any generic type parameters, and *if* there isn't an exact non-generic match, then the compiler will attempt to deduce the parameters on your behalf, considering all of the available overloads. In this case, the fact that it knows (from static analysis) that `Func<double>` returns `double` allows it to deduce that the most applicable option would be `<double>`, using the `Task<TResult> Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)` overload.

If it cannot deduce *all* of the generic parameters, or if it cannot find a suitable set of unambiguous options for a suitable overload, it will simply give up and tell you to specify them yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer :-) I forgot about generic parameter inference.